# Initializing another class's instance variable and memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Hey all, this is something I've wondered about for a while and never really figured out.  If I allocate and initialize another class's instance variable/property (example below), am i responsible for releasing it?

In Foo, I have an instance of Bar (called bar) and want to init one of Bar's variables like so:

```
self.bar.variable1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foo is responsible for releasing the UIBarButtonItem it creates because Foo *owns* it. This can be done simply by sending an `autorelease` message to the `UIBarButtonItem`. Otherwise, this will leak.

```
self.bar.variable1 = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView] autorelease];
```

If Bar needs to keep `variable1` around, it must claim ownership of the `UIBarButtonItem`. Bar is responsible for retaining (and then releasing at some point in the future) the `UIBarButtonItem` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, whatever class is responsible for allocating the object is considered the object's owner, and is therefore responsible for deallocating the instance.  The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) gives a good description of this, particularly in the "Object Ownership and Disposal" section

Answer (score 1):

May be this will make you more easy to understand.

```
UIBarButtonItem * buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView]
self.bar.variable1 = buttonItem;
[buttonItem release];
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. unless you are not releasing it in Bar class, you have to release it.